# Why isn't the "import" subroutine capitalized in Perl

Tags: perl, naming-conventions, implicit

I am curious. Most of Perl's implicitly called subroutines must be named in all caps. TIESCALAR, DESTROY, etc. In fact [`perldoc perltoot`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perltoot.html#Destructors) says

> If constructors can have arbitrary
>   names, then why not destructors? 
>   Because while a constructor is
>   explicitly called, a destructor is
>   not.  Destruction happens
>   automatically via Perl's garbage
>   collection (GC) system, which is a
>   quick but somewhat lazy
>   reference-based GC system.  To know
>   what to call, Perl insists that the
>   destructor be named DESTROY.  Perl's
>   notion of the right time to call a
>   destructor is not well-defined
>   currently, which is why your
>   destructors should not rely on when
>   they are called.
>
> Why is DESTROY in all caps?  Perl on
>   occasion uses purely uppercase
>   function names as a convention to
>   indicate that the function will be
>   automatically called by Perl in some
>   way.  Others that are called
>   implicitly include BEGIN, END,
>   AUTOLOAD, plus all methods used by
>   tied objects, described in perltie.

Why then is the `import` subroutine left to be lower case? Does anyone have a good insight on this?

Comment: I'm afraid that there's no consistent reason, and that import is lower-case just because of historical reasons, legacy bla bla.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on DVK's answer a little, there are situations where you'd legitimately want to invoke `import` explicitly, for example when loading an optional module or auto-populating namespaces:

```
eval "require $modulename; $modulename->import( LIST ); ";
```

I can't think of any situation where you would *ever* want to invoke DESTROY, TIESCALAR, etc. explicitly.

Comment: I have used DESTROY explicitly to break circular references and make sure objects get garbage collected. You can usually do this by using weakref, but it is not always convenient.

Answer (score 6):

I'd say that "`import`" is not called implicitly. It's an explicit call issued by implementation of `use`. To quote from [perldoc use](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html):

> It is exactly equivalent to:
>
> `BEGIN { require Module; Module->import( LIST ); }`

Comment: While I agree that this is possibly the reason, I would argue that from the standpoint of both the author and the user, this is implicitly called.

Comment: Alternatively how is this different from `tie` calling TIESCALAR? I can see that DESTROY has more magic around it.

Answer (score 1):

It's simply an oversight in the design. It's too late to change.